# Multiple text fields into one database column

Tags: database, ms-access-2007

I have a little code of mine where I put few text fields from form into db.
I need to combine 3 text fields so they will be inserted into one field in table separated with a comma and i can't figure out the way to connect it.

Let's say i have test fields:

txtFieldOne, txtFieldTwo, txtFieldThree and i want to put them separated by commas into one table column, like:

```
INSERT INTO dbtable (combinedValuesOfTextFieldOneTwoAndThree) VALUES (txtFieldOne + txtFieldTwo + txtFieldThree);
```

Comment: **Don't do this!!** This violates even the **first normal form** of database design! One cell should **NEVER** store more than one piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbtable (combinedValuesOfTextFieldOneTwoAndThree) 
SELECT txtFieldOne & "," & txtFieldTwo & "," & txtFieldThree FROM sourceTable
```

Comment: That's if you have another table where you will be pulling txtFieldOne, txtFieldTwo and txtFieldThree. If you only need to concatenate values, then INSERT INTO dbtable (combinedValuesOfTextFieldOneTwoAndThree) VALUES(txtFieldOne & "," & txtFieldTwo & "," & txtFieldThree) is what you need.

Comment: Oh, You are right, it was just that simple. My example:         strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAwarieOtwarte (nrMaszyny, nazwaMaszyny, Zglaszajacy, dataZgloszenia, dataZakonczenia, godzinaZgloszenia, Przyczyna, Obszar, Telefon, Komentarz) VALUES ('" & Me!txtNrMaszyny & "', '" & Me!txtNazwa & "', '" & Me!txtZglaszajacy & "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtGodzina & "', '" & Me!listPrzyczyna & "," & Me!txtNazwa & "," & Me!txtNrMaszyny & "," & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtTel & "', '" & Me!txtKomentarz & "');"